# PHP array to another and json

Tags: php, arrays

SQL output use for loop on the array , get only data to the new array and one key name ,data=>
mycode:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Alldata";
if($result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql))
{
    $rows = array();
    $newdata = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
}
for($i = 0; $i <= 6; $i++){
    $newdata['data'][$i] = $rows[$i]['poo'];
}
echo json_encode($newdata);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => 123
            [1] => 456
            [2] => 789
            [3] => 111
            [4] => 222
            [5] => 333
        )

)
{"data":["123","456","789","111","222","333"]}
```

but I want is like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
           
            [data] => 123,456,789,111,222,333
        )
)
[{"data":"123,444,555,666,777"}]
```

How to get this output?
thank you!!

Comment: Why do you want the data in this form? Seems backwards.

Comment: [`implode(',', $yourArray)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you want the data as a comma-separated string but if you want to do something like this then you can simply [`implode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode) a single column from the result set. To get the column use [`array_column()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

Change your code to this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Alldata";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$rows = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$newdata[] = [
    'data' => implode(',', array_column($rows, 'poo'))
];
echo json_encode($newdata);
```

It produces this output:

> [{"data":"1,2,3,6,7,8,9,10,11,12"}]

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [data] => 123,456,789,111,222,333 ) [1] => Array ( [data] => 456,666,777,888,333) )how to do it?

Comment: Do you mean split into groups of 6 elements each? Use `array_chunk()`

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick, simple use implode function.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Alldata";
if($result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql))
{
    $rows = array();
    $newdata = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
}
for($i = 0; $i <= 6; $i++){
    $newdata['data'][$i] = $rows[$i]['poo'];
}
$glue = implode(",",$newdata['data']);
$newdata['data'] = $glue;
echo json_encode($newdata);
```

Comment: Why not just get the value directly in your while-loop instead of adding an extra foreach?

Comment: If I need add array ...like this

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
           
            [data] => 123,456,789,111,222,333
        )
 [1] => Array
        (
            [data] => 456,666,777,888,333)
) )how to do it?